# Soft drop shadow of a text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to achieve such a soft drop shadow **using only `tikz`!** without `contour`, `pgf-blur` or simmilar.
[image]

I was searching for the solution, but was not managed to find one with tikz.

However, I have noticed a tikz's library called `shadows`. I tried to implement that, but I'm getting a rectangular shaddow instead of text-like.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[preaction={blur shadow={shadow xshift=-.5mm,shadow yshift=.5mm}}] at (1,1) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably, if I am bale to blur the text using `tikz`, it will for for me, I will just put one behind and it is done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a hundred percent handcrafted pure-Ti*k*Z solution (no libraries no nothing).

It does pretty much the same thing as `pgf-blur` or `contour` I guess.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\randamp}{0.005}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\totshadow}{30}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0.2em,yshift=-0.2ex]
   \path[opacity=0.01] foreach \nshadow [evaluate=\nshadow as \angshadow using \nshadow/\totshadow*360] in {1,...,\totshadow}{
        node at (\angshadow:\randamp) {Text}
    };
\end{scope}
\node[] at (0,0) {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT : Here is something that aims at begin a bit closer to the request in the comments. Without the definition of the parameters "spread" and others, I can't know for sure though.**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\shadowangle}{132}
\newlength{\shadowdistance}
\pgfmathsetlength{\shadowdistance}{0.2ex}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shadowopacity}{0.9}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shadowspread}{0.002}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\shadowsize}{0}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\totshadow}{100}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[opacity={\shadowopacity/\totshadow},shift={({\shadowangle-180}:\shadowdistance)},scale={1+\shadowsize}]
    foreach \nshadow [evaluate=\nshadow as \angshadow using \nshadow/\totshadow*360] in {1,...,\totshadow}{
        node at (\angshadow:\shadowspread) {Text}
        };
    \node[] at (0,0) {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am wondering whether it is possible to manage "spread" and "size" like so: https://imgur.com/yZPK60w with your method?

Comment: Basically you can have the same result with the current parameters, play a bit with randamp and totshadow and you will see

Comment: @antshar I tried something a bit closer to what you showed in your comment. If you have resources about these settings the maths should not be that hard.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: @antshar I saw some stuff about CSS or illustrator settings, which I tried to replicate as best as possible, but they never really tell how it is working in the background. Let me know if you find additional informations on their settings.