# Syntax for special looking (complex) root?

Tags: root

I am looking for the command/package that can produce the following root: [image]

I have found something calling this a "complex" root - but nothing really more. Does anyone have some more information to this? Thanks!

Comment: By "special looking", are you referring to the shadowed appearance?

Comment: In the meantime....welcome to the TeX.SE community.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming words. Sorry if my question was not clear enough: by special looking I am referring to the drop shadow, how to produce this effect or if it is already incorporated into a package and what it actually means in a mathematical context.

Comment: For the record, that's _really subtle_ if it actually means something different from an un-shadowed root sign. I'd probably assume my printer made a mistake or the paper bled a little before I'd even _consider_ that it might be significant.

Comment: I can't imagine what that might mean in a mathematical context. Can you give us a clue? I'm curious!

Answer (score 8):

You can typeset the grey square root a bit lowered and moved right over a phantom in a box of width zero, then the normal square root.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\newcommand{\specialsqrt}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \color{gray}%
    \raisebox{-0.75pt}{%
      $\kern0.75pt\sqrt{\displaystyle\phantom{#1}\kern-0.75pt}$%
    }%
  }%
  \sqrt{\displaystyle#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\specialsqrt{(x_R-y_{yaw})^2+(y_{yaw})^2+(z_{yaw})^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've never seen such a construction.

Answer (score 7):

How about the following code, inspired by [Soft drop shadow of a text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545983/soft-drop-shadow-of-a-text)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\randamp}{0.005}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\totshadow}{30}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0.1em,yshift=-0.2ex]
   \path[opacity=0.01] foreach \nshadow [evaluate=\nshadow as \angshadow using \nshadow/\totshadow*360] in {1,...,\totshadow}{
        node at (\angshadow:\randamp) {$\displaystyle\sqrt{\phantom{(x_r-x_{\mathit{yaw}})^2+(y_{\mathit{yaw}})^2+(z_{\mathit{yaw}})^2}}$}
    };
\end{scope}
\node[] at (0,0) {$\displaystyle\sqrt{(x_r-x_{\mathit{yaw}})^2+(y_{\mathit{yaw}})^2+(z_{\mathit{yaw}})^2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here, I define `\ssqrt` using a `\stackinset`.  The horizontal and vertical offsets of the shadow can be adjusted by changing the `.6pt` and `.7pt` arguments of `\stackinset`, respectively.  Likewise the color choice for the shadow, `gray!70`, can similarly be adjusted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine, xcolor, newtxmath, newtxtext,amsmath}
\stackMath
\newcommand\ssqrt[2][]{%
  \stackinset{r}{.6pt}{b}{.7pt}
  {\displaystyle\sqrt[#1]{\phantom{#2}}}
  {\displaystyle\textcolor{gray!70}{\sqrt{\textcolor{black}{#2}}}}
}
\begin{document}

$x\ssqrt{(x_r-x_{\text{yaw}})^2+(y_{\text{yaw}})^2+(z_{\text{yaw}})^2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Peraphs the "2" have the font CM because there are togheter newtxmath and amsmath. After there is not the first "x" and the r is "R".

Comment: @Sebastiano The leading `x` is there to demonstrate that the baseline of the revised sqrt material has not been altered.  I chose the tx fonts because the illustration of the OP was in that font.

Comment: Ah ok...excuse me very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for asking. No excuse needed

Answer (score 3):

I have used an old package named [shadowtext](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/shadowtext/shadowtext.pdf) but the shadow invades the whole expression and not only the root and it hurts the eyes to see it :-(.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{shadowtext}


\begin{document}
\shadowoffset{.8pt}
\shadowtext{$\sqrt{(x_R-x_{\text{yaw}})^2+(y_{\text{yaw}})^2+(z_{\text{yaw}})^2}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An adaptation can be made to this effect:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\shadowoffset{.8pt}
\newcommand\ssqrt[1]{%
  \bgroup\ooalign{\shadowtext{$\sqrt{\phantom{#1}}$}\cr\hfil$#1$}\egroup}
\begin{document}
\[\ssqrt{(x_R-x_{\text{yaw}})^2+(y_{\text{yaw}})^2+(z_{\text{yaw}})^2}\]

\[\ssqrt{3x}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like `\newcommand\ssqrt[1]{\bgroup\ooalign{\shadowtext{$\sqrt{\phantom{#1}}$}\cr\hfil$#1$}\egroup}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You are free to improved my answer. I will happy to see the difference. Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes one billion of thank you.